# How to intercept a navigation in gatsby.js

Tags: navigation, gatsby

On my GatsbyJs page, I want to show a dialog form when the user is trying to navigate away from the page, giving the user the option of canceling the navigation

I don't know how to do it in Gatsby

Any hint?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your specs but you can try placing a "fake" link that triggers a modal with two buttons (OK/navigate and KO/close), and it's the OK button the one that performs the navigation while the KO button dismisses the modal.

Something like:

```
const SomePage = () => {
  const handleClick = (to) => {
    //open modal here
    //if the user clicks the OK button
    navigate(to);
  };

  return (
    <section>
      <p>Some Content</p>
      <div onClick={() => (handleClick = "/some-url")}>Fake Link</div>
    </section>
  );
};
```

More details about `navigate` function: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-link/#how-to-use-the-navigate-helper-function